# Elasticsearch, tire and autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

Good day. I have elasticsearch in my rails app using tire.
I have many names in my db. And I want to search for them like search_query: "alex ivan", and the output should be ["Alexander Ivanov", "Alex Ivanenko] etc. (Real names from db)
I tried to make it with [this article](http://blog.tipter.com/blog/2013/06/16/autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-and-tire/) but it's not searching. So I've made a quickhack:

```
params[:search_query] = params[:search_query].split(" ").map{|a|a<<("*")}.join(" ")
```

Is it a good decision or I can do it with analyzers etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did using analyzers for doing a search on names of businesses when I used ElasticSearch.  Place this inside your mapping block and modify the index appropriately -- I think this will give you what you want:

```
indexes :name, :type => 'multi_field', :fields => {
  :name => { :type => 'string', :analyzer => 'standard' },
  :"name.exact" => { :type => 'string', :index => :not_analyzed }
}
```

Then inside your `search` and `query` blocks, something like:

```
search do
  query do

    # either a must match for exact match
    boolean(:minimum_number_should_match => 1) do  
      must { string "name:#{<variable>}" }
    end

    # or a broader match
    string "name:#{<variable>}*"
  end
end
```

Comment: It's like my variant, but you only make a sort of condition for exect mach?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: your "name:#{<variable>}*" == .map{|a|a<<("*")} from my code. So you are using the same logic?

Comment: Well, maybe.  I'm not sure if ElasticSearch translates the `name:#{<variable>}` into the map statement...